# Can Specs2 compare sequence elements with one of the existing matchers?

Tags: scala, specs2

I want to compare 2 sequences of doubles in a specs2 test, something along the lines of:

```
actualValues must containTheSameElementsAs(expectedValues, _ beCloseTo _)
```

I can write a manual comparison like

```
actualValues must containTheSameElementsAs(expectedValues, (a, b) => math.abs(a - b) < 0.001)
```

but that seems a bit pointless as beCloseTo is already available.

On a wider note, is there a good source of documentation for Specs2? I looked at [the user guide](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.0.1/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html) but the search in that for "containsAllOf" shows no results and the matchers section doesn't have any entry about collections as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of collection matches should be expressible with `contain` + combinators. In this case you can write

```
List(1.3, 1.7) must contain(beCloseTo(1.5 +/- 0.5)).forall
```

where `forall` tests each element. You could replace `forall` with `atLeastOnce` if you wanted to test that only one element satisfies your property.

You could also write it like this if you want the "forall" word to appear sooner in your statement

```
forall(List(1.0, 2.0)) { n =>
  n must beCloseTo(1.5 +/- 0.5)
}
```

This comes from the `MatcherImplicits` trait mixed into the `Specification` but I agree, this is not well-documented.

Comment: Thank you that's great.
If you write a Specs2 book, then we would get a great resource, and you would get somewhat compensated for all your great work on it ;-)

Comment: Most authors I talked to told me that writing a book was terribly time consuming and not so financially rewarding :-). At this stage what's more realistic is to grow the number of contributors and have targeted PRs to improve the doc. The one thing I would like to do though is follow this pattern: https://www.divio.com/en/blog/documentation. I wish I knew about it before.